# What should I do for storing images in PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Should I use Boolean and store images in MySQL database or should I store images somewhere in web space?

> example: /images

Please help.

Comment: store images on web sever or any server which delivers your site static content . and store image paths in mysql

Comment: okay but why i shouldn't use `Boolean `

Comment: the decision will be based on no of images and site traffic , if its low then you can use boolean , but if you have high traffic site with larger images then it will degrade DB performance , if you keep your file in static content server or use any CDN servers then performance will be good and images get cached on browser and CDN based on URL you stored in DB